# How do I use a negative DURATION formatted cell from Google Spreadsheets in Google Scripts?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Spreadsheets and I have a sheet in the following format:

```
Start | End     | Partial result | Expected | Total
08:00 | 12:00   | 04:00          | 05:00    | -01:00
14:00 | 18:00   | 04:00          | 05:00    | -01:00
----------------------------------------------------
                                 | Month tot| -02:00
```

As you can see, it allows for negative duration stamps. This is causing me a lot of trouble in Google Scripts.

I want to email everyone a monthly summary.

Here's a simple snippet:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(...);
var monthlyTotal = sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue(); //The total is at cell A1
```

Now, when I debug, it shows my monthlyTotal as a `Date` object, set to `Tue Dec 26 1899 14:50:28 GMT-0300 (BRT)` (this is quite correct, my result is `-81:16:00`, it subtracted `81:16` from `1900-01-01 00:00:00`, no issues there).

Now, I have no idea how to get back to a duration format (`-81:16`). I have tried converting this date object to a negative timestamp, but `+monthlyTotal` returns what I believe to be a wrong value (`-2212132172000`).

I have no idea how to turn a `Date` object from **before** 1900 to a timestamp and, as a consequence, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

Don't use `.getValue()` on date/time cells. Instead,  put `=TO_TEXT(A1)` somewhere (or already have A1 containing something like `TO_TEXT(SUM(E2:E))`, and use `.getValue()` to get that **string**. Numbers and strings pass between sheets and scripts reliably, unlike dates and times.

#### Explanation

Unlike the Unix operating systems for which the epoch begins at 1970-01-01, Google Sheets use `December 30, 1899 0:00:00` as 0 time, which you can see by entering `=TO_DATE(0)` anywhere in your spreadsheet.

In principle, you could apply `.valueOf()` to the duration value returned by `.getValue()`: this returns the JavaScript timestamp, which is the number of **milli**seconds from the beginning of 1970. Dividing by 1000 gives the Unix timestamp.

However, this is problematic because Unix timestamp and consequently JavaScript timestamp are measured from the moment `1970-01-01 00:00:00` **in UTC**, while the 0 mark of Google Sheets is in the **local timezone**.

If you try to adjust for timezones using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();` be warned that script time zone may be different from sheet time zone: [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()) this is "a frequent source of scripting bugs". The method `Spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` gives the timezone of Spreadsheet itself, but it's returned as a string like 'America/New York', which [does not directly translate to an offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712419/get-utc-offset-from-timezone-in-javascript).

Comment: Fantastic answer. This is exactly what I had been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I have edited my question to reflect the TIMESTAMP difference (1900, not 1970). Thank you once again.

Comment: Nowadays it's easier because we could use `getDisplayValue`