# Hide columns with certain dates on open

Tags: google-sheets

Got a sheet containing dates in the first row.

I would like to hide on open all columns (some are already hidden manually) left of the column which date is closest to the current date

Comment: I had initially appended the new question on to this one, but they are considerably different situations.  Please ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires a script with a function `onOpen()`. Since you are asking about *dates* and not times, I'm going to break [my own advice](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80554) "do not use `.getValue` on date/time cells".

Here is a script that does what you described: grabs the dates in the first row, compares them to the present time (ignoring the potential timezone issues: UTC in Google Script vs local time in Sheets), and picks the closest. Then hides the columns to the left of the closest.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // or .getSheets()[0]; to apply to the first sheet.
  var width = sheet.getDataRange().getWidth();
  var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, width).getValues().valueOf();  
  var today = Date.now();
  var minDiff = 1e9;
  var imin = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < dates[0].length; i++) {
    if (Math.abs(dates[0][i]-today) < minDiff) {
      imin = i;
      minDiff = Math.abs(dates[0][i]-today);
    }
  }
  sheet.hideColumns(1, imin);
}
```

Whether some of the columns were previously hidden doesn't matter.

You may want to play it safer by hiding one column less, with `sheet.hideColumns(1, imin-1);` to provide a cushion against timezone discrepancy. Also, nearest date could be before or after today's; this is also worth considering.

Comment: Obviously only the owner triggers this script. I would like that shared users with write permission could also trigger