# Working With Durations In Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I'm trying to write a function in Google Apps Script to manipulate durations calculated in Google Sheets. The cells holding the durations look like:

```
18:40:00
26:42:01
```

When I pass a duration into my code it appears to come in as a date object. So I've been using `Date.getHours()` et al to pull out the components of the time. But when the hours exceeds 23, it comes out mod 24.

Where did the "days" part of the duration go? Is there a method I can call on the Date object to get it?

Comment: By one hand, please avoid including more than one question in the body of a question, by the other hand asking for "best *something*" without describing what means **best** in the question context makes the question primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

Working with date, time and specifically duration is a pain in JavaScript, and Google Sheets does not make it much easier.

A [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (which is really a *datetime* object) is not suited for working with durations. A datetime is a lot more complex than it seems at first.

So when you ask

> Where did the "days" part of the duration go?

... there is really no secure way of converting a duration to a number of days, since you don't know *which* day, in which timezone you're talking about. In my region, daylight savings time ended October 27, 03:00:00 (this year), meaning that a period spanning from October 27 00:00:00 through October 28 00:00:00 is actually *25* hours. Different countries have different rules for daylight savings time, adding to the confusion.

See [this article](http://www.dadhacker.com/blog/?p=1585) for more examples on how dates are difficult to calculate with.

My advise would be to ditch the entire Duration feature, and decide which unit you want to work with: Days, hours or minutes. If you choose to work with hours, and want to specify a duration of *1 hour and 30 minutes*, enter `1.5` in that cell.

If you need to display `1.5` hours as `1 hours 30 minutes` somewhere, write a simple formula for that - but use it only for display purposes.

---

If you really want to work with `Date`, some experimentation on a simple spreadsheet might clarify a few things. I set up [this spreadsheet for experimentation](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13ykvl6C5jC87CwxfXXBM8vVPXs12aJ_OYjPcdX8ez9M/edit#gid=0) - feel free to copy it to your own drive.

In cell `A2` I enter a number of days, e.g. `1.5`. Cell `B2` is formatted as Duration, with the formula `=A2`, so it simply displays `1.5` as a Duration: `24:00:00`.

For cell `C2` I have written a small script that dumps some debug information about the `B2` value:

```
function outputValueInfo(value) {
  return [value, typeof value, JSON.stringify(value), value.getTime()];
}
```

This causes the `C2-C5` to display

```
12/31/1899
object
"1899-12-31T11:00:00.000Z"
-2209035600000
```

So a *duration  of 1.5 days* is represented by a Date object with the value `1899-12-31T11:00:00.000Z`. Not the easiest thing to work with.

Enter a value of `0` in `A2`, and watch `C4` change to `"1899-12-31T11:00:00.000Z"`. We could use this as a base date, and compare it to the *1.5 days* duration date.

"Subtracting" two dates is easiest done by looking at [the date's `getTime()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), which gives the *number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch*, which is `00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970`.

By comparing each duration with the base date, we can write a function:

```
function durationInDays(date) {
  var baseDate = new Date("1899-12-29T23:00:00.000Z");
  return (date.getTime() - baseDate.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
}
```

Hopefully this can be a starting point for your calculation needs.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script / JavaScript doesn't include a "native" way to handle durations but you could use a library like moment.js to add several methods to handle them but this could imply a *steeped learning curve*. A simpler solution is to read the duration from the spreadsheet as "displayed value" by using `getDisplayValue` instead of the "inherent value" got when using `getValue`, then use text handling methods to parse hours, minutes and seconds from the spreadsheet duration value.

Example

```
/**
 * Returns the hours part from a string (HH:mm:ss)
 *
 * @param {string} duration A string representing duration HH:mm:ss
 */
function getHours(duration){
  return parseInt(duration.split(':')[0]);
}
```

Related

- [How do I use a negative DURATION formatted cell from Google Spreadsheets in Google Scripts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80547/88163)

Reference

- [How do I use momentsjs in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22410210/1595451) (Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can't manipulate duration calculated. We need to convert them to numbers first, and then we can manipulate number values calculated. After that, we convert them back to duration.

For example, we want to add 2 duration at 2 ranges durationRg1 and durationRg2 into the range totalDuragionRg.

```
totalDurationRg.setValue(Add2Duration(durationRg1, durationRg2));
//set the totalDurationRg to Duration format if you have not done it.
totalDurationRg.setNumberFormat('[h]:mm:ss');

function Add2Duration(durationRg1, durationRg2)
{
     durationRg1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');
     var dur1numVal = durationRg1.getValue();
     //  set back to duration format
     durationRg1.setNumberFormat('[h]:mm:ss');

     durationRg2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');
     var dur2numVal = durationRg2.getValue();
     //  set back to duration format
     durationRg2.setNumberFormat('[h]:mm:ss');

     return dur1numVal + dur2numVal;
}
```